# How to use angular.bind(self, fn, args)

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js. I was gone through the angular api references,
I had seen function called angular.bind(self, fn, args).
I could not understand the usage of this function. Can anyone explain this function with one example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used in **Function Currying**. An example with JavaScript:

```
var concat = function(input1) {
  return function(input2) {
    console.log(input1 + ", " + input2);
  };
};

var externalFunction = concat("Hello");
externalFunction("World!"); // gives: "Hello, World!"
```

This allows you to use only some parameters and not all, for example `concant("Hello")` instead of `concant("Hello","World!")`. You can imagine using a defined variable as one of the parameters, whereas you fill in the second one from a user input. The same concept can be used with AnuglarJS:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="bindController">
        <input type="number" ng-model="num" ng-change="AddValue()" />
        Adding 5: {{Add}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller('bindController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.num = 30;
        $scope.AddValue = function () {
            var addData = angular.bind(this, function (a, b) {return a + b;});
            $scope.Add = addData(5, $scope.num);
        }
        $scope.AddValue();
    }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

> ```
>  app.controller('Identity`enter code here`Controller', ['$scope',
>    function($scope) { 
>    $scope.Name = "";
>    $scope.Result = "";
>   var greet = function (greeting, punctuation) {
>     $scope.Result = greeting + ' ' + $scope.Name +''+ punctuation;
>   };
>    $scope.callBind = function () {
>     var bound = angular.bind(this, greet, 'Welcome');
>      bound('!!!!!');
>   };
>  }]);
> ```

**html**

> ```
>  <fieldset style="background-color:#DDE4E9;">          
>     <legend>AngulerJS $scope.bind() Example</legend>           
>         <div ng-controller="IdentityController">         
>           <p>{{Result}}</p>
>           <input ng-model="Name">    
>           <button ng-click="callBind()">Call Bind</button> 
>         </div>
>  </fieldset>
> ```

I Think Its Working